# Running commands in a single shell

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a shell script(this is just a sample, actual script is quiet complex, so please consider all scenarios)

```
source env.sh
binary1 -a 1 -b 2
binary2 -a 1 -b 2
```

binary1 and 2 are functions exposed by environment scripts

I need to execute these using python

Currently I am using this

```
bashShell = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
_commands = ["source env.sh", "binary1 -a 1 -b 2", "binary2 -a 1 -b 2"]
_commands.append("exit")
for cmd in self._commands:
    bashShell.stdin.write("%s\n" % cmd)

bashShell.communicate()
```

What this does is opens a bash shell using subprocess and writes all the input to stdin at once.

binary1 takes a long time to execute. Will there be any adverse effects if I write binary2 command to stdin of bash subprocess while binary1 instruction is still executing?

Note: Running these in a single shell is important as environment scripts expose some functions
Thanks.

Comment: No, there's no adverse effects. It just gets buffered in the pipe until the shell finishes the first command and reads from the pipe.

Comment: You could also send the whole thing as a single string, with commands separated by `;`.